# Enable GIT shallow clone in Cloudbees Jenkins

Tags: git, cloudbees, shallow-clone

Is it possible to enable the shallow clone option for GIT in Cloudbees Jenkins?
I am using Cloudbees Jenkins for my project. The client needs the shallow Clone option to be enabled. I couldn't find any option to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. It's possible.

(Ever since v2.4.3)

[image: Shallow clone]

More info on that here:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24728

and

https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/advanced-git-jenkins

Comment: The "Advanced Clone behaviours" are present in "Advanced Options" Tab.

Comment: @tehp, is it possible to do a Shallow fetch on top of the shallow clone?

Comment: I'm not sure @Jason, I have never tried that. If you try to find a way, you should post here for future viewers.